# For, $x\ge 0$ define, $f(x)=\frac1{x+2\cos x}.$ Determine the set, $\{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y=f(x), x\ge 0\}.$

Tags: real-analysis

For, $x\ge 0$ define, $f(x)=\frac1{x+2\cos x}.$ Determine the set, $$\{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y=f(x), x\ge 0\}.$$

Unless, I am missing something, the phrase "determine the set" sounds, like finding the range of the function $f(x).$ If that's the case, then I simply observed that $\cos x$ is a continuous function and as $-1\leq \cos x\leq 1$, so, $y=\cos x$ takes all the real values in the interval $[-1,1].$ Also, we note that $x+2\cos x\neq 0.$ These implies that $x+2\cos x$ can take up any real value, except $0$. We thus may conclude, the range of the set is the set $\Bbb R-\{0\}.$ Hence, $$\{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y=f(x), x\ge 0\}=\Bbb R-\{0\}.$$

Question 1: Am I correctly judging the sense of this question?

Question 2: The solution I did, is valid. I found the invalidity in the part, where  I made the claim, "These implies that $x+2\cos x$ can take up any real value". Seeing the graph, made me believe, that it  does not take the negative values when $x\geq 0$ and even then, the function $x+2\cos x$ do not even take all the positive real values, as well, when $x\geq  0.$ It becomes very obvious, from a graph that when $x\geq 0$, $f(x)$ is bounded. Now, for the question: When I made that faulty claim, the thing that went on in my mind, was that $\cos x$ takes all the values in $[-1,1],$ and as, $x$ is non-negative, we can generate any positive  real value. This is because, say we want to generate $r$ as an output from the function $f(x)$ (, where $r$  is a real number) , then we can take $x$ as $a\in\Bbb R^+$ and hope that $\frac{1}{a+\cos a}=r.$ But this intuition is faulty. I want to specifically know, how to save myself from these erring intutive thoughts?

Comment: I agree that the questions seemingly asks to find the range of the function. I do not agree that the function can produce negative values on the given domain.

Comment: Also, it seems there is a positive maximum.

Answer (score 1):

We can note that it is asking for the range, *with $x\geq 0$*. So you're first guess is not quite right since we are taking the reciprocal of $x + 2\cos x$ so this condition actually does matter. A quick look of the graph of the function online might help.

We can solve this problem by noting that $f(x)$ is differentiable for all $x\geq 0$, thus it follows that we can find its minima and maxima by finding points $f'(x) = 0$. By regular calculus,
$$
f'(x) = \frac{2\sin x - 1}{(x+2\cos x)^2}.
$$
We can note that $x + 2\cos x \geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$, which we can easily observe from the fact that $x + 2\cos x$ takes on the value $2$ at $x=0$. Then finding the critical points is the same as finding
\begin{align}
2\sin x &= 1 \\
\sin x &= \frac12\\
x &=\pi/6 + 2\pi n , 5\pi/6 + 2\pi n \qquad n\in \mathbb N
\end{align}
Therefore, all potential minima, maxima have the forms \begin{align}
f(\pi/6 + 2\pi n) &= \frac{1}{\pi/6 + 2\pi n + \sqrt 3}\\
f(5\pi/6 + 2\pi n) &= \frac{1}{5\pi/6 + 2\pi n - \sqrt 3}
\end{align}
First we can see that taking $n\to \infty$ takes the above values to $0$, thus the minimum is $0$ (this is also easily observed from just the function itself). It is easy to see that to maximize $f,$ we want to minimize the value in the denominator. Thus we want
$$
x_{max} = \arg\min \left[\left\{\pi/6 + 2\pi n +\sqrt 3 : n\in \mathbb N \right\} \cup\left\{5\pi/6 + 2\pi n - \sqrt 3 : n\in \mathbb N \right\} \right]
$$
But we can easily observe that $x_{max} = 5\pi/6 - \sqrt3$ (an easy proof exercise). Thus the maximum is
$$
f(x_{max}) = \frac{1}{5\pi/6 - \sqrt3}
$$
thus we can conclude that the range of $f(x)$ for $x\geq 0$ is
$$
\left(0, \frac{1}{5\pi/6 - \sqrt 3}\right]
$$

Comment: How are you so sure that there exists a maxima and a minima without checking double derivatives ?

Comment: Also how did you claim that there exists no critical points for which the 1st derivative is undefined ? To show the first derivative cannot be  really undefined at any points, you need to show, $x+2\cos x\neq 0$. But you haven't shown it?

Comment: I skipped showing that $x+2\cos x>0$ because I think it is an easy enough exercise. I did not need to find the second derivatives since I use the fact that any minima or maxima, if they exist, are attained at points where $f'(x)=0$. I in fact did it this way to intentionally avoid cumbersome second derivative calculations.

Comment: You wrote, "We can note that $x + 2\cos x \geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$ . Is this is a standard fact ?